# How to use Jenkins environment variables in config.ini file?

Tags: jenkins

I am looking to use a database username/password in my `config.ini` file. I have the following withCredentials line in my `Jenkinsfile`:

`withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'database', usernameVariable: 'DATABASE_USER', passwordVariable: 'DATABASE_PASSWORD')])`

I don't explicitly call this `config.ini` file in my `Jenkinsfile`, however I do use a bash script to:

`export CONFIG_FILE='config.ini'`

Is there any way to set these accordingly in my `config.ini`:

```
DB_USERNAME = {DATABASE_USER}
DB_PASSWORD = {DATABASE_PASSWORD}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash can do this for you. You have two options:

1. Use [envsubst](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/envsubst-Invocation.html). You'll need to install it on all of your nodes (it's usually part of the gettext package).
2. Use evil eval

Full example:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        label 'linux' // make sure we're running on Linux
    }
    
    environment {
        USER = 'theuser'
        PASSWORD = 'thepassword'
    }
    
    stages {
        stage('Write Config') {
            steps {
                sh 'echo -n "user=$USER\npassword=$PASSWORD" > config.ini'
            }    
        }
        
        stage('Envsubst') {
            steps {
                sh 'cat config.ini | envsubst > config_envsubst.ini'
                sh 'cat config_envsubst.ini'
            }
        }
        
        stage('Eval') {
            steps {
                sh 'eval "echo \"$(cat config.ini)\"" > config_eval.ini'
                sh 'cat config_eval.ini'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[This this Stackexchange question for more options.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/294835/replace-environment-variables-in-a-file-with-their-actual-values)